# How to see how many AsyncTask Tasks are running in the background of a android application

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask

is it possible to log in log cat how many Async task are currently running which are not completed? i have problem where a task will not stopping running after i run few tasks in my app, please help thanks. using eclipse and java as programming language.

Comment: This might apply to you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6924939/1449972

Comment: Not that I know of. You can log them yourself: log when it starts and log when it ends.

Comment: Works perfectly however  it hangs sometimes and never ends so can't figure out what causes the issue.